# Getting the GUID of a file with client object model?

Tags: client-object-model

Is it possible to get the GUID if I have the path to a file?

Any sample code available?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the ClientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl() method.

Here is a sample Code:

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://contoso");

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Asset Library");

File file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Asset Library/filename.png");

ctx.Load(file);

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

ListItem item = file.ListItemAllFields;

ctx.Load(item);

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

string idAsString = item["UniqueId"].ToString();

Guid id = new Guid(idAsString);
```

Answer (score 2):

ashwnacharya's solution is correct. but you can optimize it, such that only one query execution need :

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://contoso");

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Asset Library");

File file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Asset Library/filename.png");

ListItem item = file.ListItemAllFields;

ctx.Load(item);

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

string idAsString = item["UniqueId"].ToString();

Guid id = new Guid(idAsString);
```